# kernel openvpn segfault

Tags: centos, openvpn

e..
I have some trouble about OPENVPN these days..
At first,I find that the OPENVPN is always down. Then I try to restart it.But after a short while,It's down again.

Then I check /var/log/messages and find something below

```
openvpn[4338]: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:48484 Re-using SSL/TLS context
openvpn[4338]: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:48484 LZO compression initialized
openvpn[4338]: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:48484 [abc.abc_] Peer Connection Initiated with xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:48484
kernel: openvpn[4338]: segfault at 0000000000000018 rip 00002b75ca30ca2e rsp 00007fff153806a0 error 4
```

Obviously,OPENVPN is Down.

So,I just want to know what's wrong here.....

P.s. The username should be `abc.abc`.But it shows that is `abc.abc_`
Is there something wrong?

CentOS 5.4 x64
Linux 2.6.18-238.9.1.el5

My English is very pool... :(

Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

It fails just after the connection is initiated, which means just after the SSL is negotiated. This would indicate some incompability between SSL on server and on client. Try **yum update** so with newer version it might work better. Also try to upgrade OpenVPN to the latest version too.
It's because software is tested always with the latest release of the operating system, so it's best to run the same.